# How to delete a link to a bug from a test execution in Kiwi TCMS

Tags: kiwi-tcms

## Steps to reproduce

1. [Configure external bug tracker](https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin.html#configure-external-bug-trackers). In my case [Redmine](https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/tcms.issuetracker.types.html#tcms.issuetracker.types.Redmine)
2. Complete a test run
3. Use ‘Report bug’ to create a new bug in redmine

## Expected result

1. A bug is created and linked to the test case run
2. There is a way to delete the link to the bug

## Actual result

1. As expected :+1:
2. There is no way to delete the link, or at least I can't find it

## Screenshot

Some parts are blurred:

[Test Case Run with linked bug reports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSfkf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting links to bugs (or anything else) from a Test Execution is currently not possible.

You may open a feature request on GitHub Issues to request this functionality.

However these URLs serve the purpose of traceability b/w your bug reports & test executions. If the link is removed that breaks traceability. You'd better have a very good justification for that because it doesn't sound like something a test team would like to do.

Comment: I added the screenshot.